# Cloned ActiveRecord object sends null id to Postgres during save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to save a copy of an ActiveRecord object so I'm using something like:

```
@original = Model.find(params[:id])
@copy = @original.clone
```

However, when I attempt to save this to Postgres:

> PGError: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

In the console:

> > > @copy.id
> > >       => nil

How do I get ActiveRecord to not send the id column in the INSERT statement?

**Update:**

The problem went away after I made a small change:

```
@new = Model.new(params[:model])
@original = Model.find(x)
@clone = @original.clone
@new.foreign_key_id = @clone.foreign_key_id
```

I replaced the last line with:

```
@new.foreign_key_id = @original.foreign_key_id
```

This change removed 'id' from the INSERT statement. After a successful experiment with this change, I immediately reverted the code and attempted to reproduce the error. I have been unable to reproduce the error. Friday the 13th, maybe?

Comment: Please post the SQL that Rails generates so we can see what it is trying to insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling [ActiveRecord::Base#clone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002333), not Object#clone.
ActiveRecord::Base#clone is essentially creates a new instance of the model, copies the attributes hash and deletes the id key. Essentially doing what Luke Franci Suggests.

I'm sure this is a PostgreSQL problem. Because this code works with MySQL.

```
@clone = @original.clone
@clone.save
```

The error your having might have something to do with the way that PostgreSQL handles auto-increment. I can't tell if ActiveRecord is trying to pass the undefined id in the INSERT statement, when it shouldn't be, or if something went wrong with definition.

I don't know enough about postreges to diagnose the problem. But I suspect the root of your problem might be in the migration defining your table.

Out of curiosity what is the result of `Model.new(@original.attributes) == @original.clone` ?

Comment: Good call. I didn't realize ActiveRecord overrode Ruby's clone method. This should be totally fine to call.

Comment: The result was false. I updated the question above to include a solution to this problem, but I think I must have done something else somehow to cause this problem because I can't reproduce it. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess...but is `new_record?` returning true for the cloned object?

It might be better to create a new model object and set the attributes equal to the old one, like this:

```
@copy = Model.new
@copy.attributes = @original.attributes
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Worked for me. Even simpler as @copy = Model.new(@original.attributes).